# View Month and Year of Group calendar

Tags: filter, groups, view, sharepoint-calendar

I have setup a group calendar using this article
http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2014/06/create-color-coded-group-calendar-sharepoint-2013-step-step.html
Now I see all the users in week view with all of their events.

Now I would like to setup a month and year view.
I have followed this article
http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/11/howto-filter-items-current-calendar-month-view-sharepoint/

I have created the columns of one called 
Start of month it is 
a calculated type
with the following formula
=DATE(YEAR([End Time]),MONTH([End Time]),1)
and a another column called 
end of month
a calculated type
with the following formula
=DATE(YEAR([End Time]),MONTH([End Time])+1,1)-1

Then I go and create a new filter called
This Month 
with a filter of 
Start of Month column 
is less then or equal to
[Today]
And
End of Month column
is greater than or equal to
[Today]

When I select this view it just shows me the regular week group view. but with no events.

I am using Sharepoint 2013.

Thanks in advance